# What does Select Max return in VBA when there are multiple maximum values?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know that max returns the maximun value in the recordset. According to the docs

> You could use this functions to return the lowest and highest freight
>   cost

However, if there are multiple maximum value. Does the recordset have all the records containing the max value or just one max value.

```
rst.Open "SELECT Max(InvNum)as MaxInv FROM [INVD]"
```

I have a while loop setup like this

```
While Not rst.EOF
 //Do something
Wend
```

And I tried the same code without using while loop

```
//Do Something
```

Both cases is giving me the same result. So I don't know whether it is just one value or lots of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will return the maximum value found in the column whether that value occurs once or more times.

[MS Access Max SQL function](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/max.php)

Edit: that is, it does not offer a count of the number of times that value occurs.

If you want the count of those occurrences of your peak value you would need to evaluate your recordset and count/identify the rows containing that value.

Something like `SELECT ID, COLUMN2 FROM [invd] WHERE InvNum=(Select Max(invNum) from [invd])` may help illustrate that